# Space character in regex is not recognised

Tags: regex, perl

I'm writing a simple program - please see below for my code with comments. Does anyone know why the space character is not recognised in line 10? When I run the code, it finds the :: but does not replace it with a space.

```
1  #!/usr/bin/perl
2
3  # This program replaces :: with a space
4  # but ignores a single :
5
6  $string = 'this::is::a:string';
7
8  print "Current: $string\n";
9 
10 $string =~ s/::/\s/g;
11 print "New: $string\n";
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try `s/::/ /g` instead of `s/::/\s/g`.

The `\s` is actually a character class representing *all* whitespace characters, so it only makes sense to have it in the regular expression (the first part) rather than in the replacement string.

Answer (score 4):

Use `s/::/ /g`. `\s` only denotes whitespace on the matching side, on the replacement side it becomes `s`.

Answer (score 4):

Replace the `\s` with a real space.

The `\s` is shorthand for a whitespace matching pattern.  It isn't used when specifying the replacement string.

Answer (score 3):

Replace string should be a literal space, i.e.:

```
$string =~ s/::/ /g;
```